# Can't achieve 100% data locality with HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, partitioning

I have 10 nodes with hadoop/hbase.

I create table with 100 regions and predefined split keys: 001, 002 ... 099

I assign regions `001-009` to first node, regions `010-019` to second node and so on, with hbase `move` command. It worked, I see correct distribution in hbase ui.

I add 1M rows to table, each row has key prefix from 000 to 099 based on key hash, I can assure that I have almost equal number of rows per region. Let's say 10k rows per region, 1M rows total.
Data is populated from other table with map reduce using HTable api.

If I check regions size using `hdfs dfs -du -h /hbase/data/default/my_table` I see they are almost the same ( +/- 5% )

The problem is, most of regions have 100% data locality, but ~10 regions have low locality (20-60%). They are not on the same node, e.g. 3 bad regions on first node, 4 on second, 3 on third.

Why does this happen? How can I achieve 100% data locality?

p.s. major compaction does not fix it

Comment: Why does it matter? Maybe you are overthinking this.

Comment: @CarlosRendon rack local tasks instead of data local tasks take x4 time to execute

Comment: yes... and so what?

Comment: @CarlosRendon job takes 1.5hours instead of 45mins